# How can I hide the article element if it contains no image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code:

```
<article class="best_places_of_town_category">
</article>
```

How can I hide article if it contains `<div>` without `<img>`? On JavaScript or CSS?

Comment: Get the `article` element in js, and check for child nodes.

Comment: I tried this: <script>

 $(document).ready(function() {
 
  if($(".best_places_of_town_category").text() == "") {

   $(".best_places_of_town_category").hide();

  }
  
 });
 
</script>   But it is not working. And I tried this $(".best_places_of_town_category").find("img[src='']").parent().hide();  It is not working too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
if ($('.best_places_of_town_category').children('div').children('img').length)
{
    console.log('Image exists');
}
else
{
    console.log('Image does not exist');
    $('.best_places_of_town_category').hide();
}    
</script>
```

Here's another example that will look through all of the children nodes of the `<article>` tag and look for an `<img>`. 

**Note:** This doesn't nest into all tags, just the first level of children in `<article>`

```
<article class="best_places_of_town_category">
    <div>div is here</div>
    <p>p tag is here</p>
    <img />
</article>

<script>
var imgExists = 0;
$('.best_places_of_town_category').children().each(function () {
    console.log('DOM Element: ' + this);
    if (this instanceof HTMLImageElement)
    {
        imgExists = 1;
    }
});
if (imgExists)
{
    console.log('Image exists within <article>');
}
else
{
    console.log('Image does not exist within <article>');
    $('.best_places_of_town_category').hide();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just tested again and block disappears only when `<img>` is missing. Are you expecting the `<img>` to be within the `<div>` or anywhere within `<article>`?

Comment: Thank you. In div element have children p and a element. I add this in your code and it works.

Comment: anywhere within article with class best_places_of_town_category

Comment: Always glad to help. I would recommend reading [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the :empty [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty).

`.best_places_of_town_category:empty {
display:none;
}`

Comment: I tried this. It is not working. I think because into article have another div element.

Answer (score 0):

Give the article an id let's say: check-img
Also give the image element an id let's say: img

Solution using JavaScript:

```
var x= document.getElementById('check-img');
var y = document.x.contains('img');
 if(y == false){
document.getElementById('check-img).style.display="none";
}
```